# Uploading Sound file to server

Tags: iphone, audio

I am trying to upload a recorded sound file that is already in m4a format to a web server.

Here is some code that needs correcting:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Disable Stop/Play button when application launches
    [stopButton setEnabled:NO];
    [playButton setEnabled:NO];

    // Set the audio file
    pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
}

- (IBAction)recordPauseTapped:(id)sender {
    // Stop the audio player before recording
    if (player.playing) {
        [player stop];
    }

    if (!recorder.recording) {
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setActive:YES error:nil];

        // Start recording
        [recorder record];
        [recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {

        // Pause recording
        [recorder pause];
        [recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [stopButton setEnabled:YES];
    [playButton setEnabled:NO];
}

- (IBAction)playTapped:(id)sender {
    if (!recorder.recording){
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
    }
}

-(IBAction)uploadSound {

    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:outputFileURL];
    NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL]];

    NSString *urlString = @"http://drewgarcia23.3owl.com/upload.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".mov\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:theData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
}
```

Everything works fine except for the uploading to server. I get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a9a590'

It has to do with this code in the `IBAction` `uploadSound`:

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:outputFileURL];
NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL]];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't recommend doing a synchronous network request on the main queue. (Your app can become unresponsive while the network request is being processed and if it takes too long, in extreme cases the watchdog process may even kill your app.) I'd suggest some form of asynchronous network upload process (e.g. `sendAsynchronousRequest`).

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are invoking `URLWithString`, passing it a `NSURL`, but it's expecting a `NSString`.

For example, consider the lines:

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:outputFileURL];
NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL]];
```

There are two problems here. First, in the first line, `outputFileURL` is already a `NSURL`, so there's no point in calling `URLWithString` when you create the `theURL` object. The `outputFileURL` is already a `NSURL`, so no conversion is necessary. Second, you have another redundant `URLWithString` call in the second line, where you're taking `theURL`, which is already a `NSURL` (or would be, if the first line succeeded).

You don't need either of these two `URLWithString` calls here. It should probably simply be:

```
NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:outputFileURL];
```

You should only call `URLWithString` when you're trying to convert a `NSString` to a `NSURL`. But you never call this if you already have a `NSURL` object.